# Find and replace within a text file using Python

Tags: python, file, text, replace

I have a text file which is about 400,000 lines long. I need to import this text file into a program which only accepts text files which are delimited with spaces or tabs, but this text file is delimited with semi-colons. There is no option in the program I am exporting the text file from (Arcmap) to change the delimination and doing find and replace in the text file itself will literally take 2 days.

I have searched for a script to do this but they all seem to replace the whole LINE of the word file with a space, instead of individually replacing each semi-colon, Leaving me with an empty text file.

Here is a sample of my text file:

```
"OID_";"POINTID";"GRID_CODE";"POINT_X";"POINT_Y"
;1;-56.000000;200900.250122;514999.750122
;2;-56.000000;200900.750122;514999.750122
;3;-56.000000;200901.250122;514999.750122
;4;-57.000000;200901.750122;514999.750122
;5;-57.000000;200902.250122;514999.750122
;6;-57.000000;200902.750122;514999.750122
;7;-57.000000;200903.250122;514999.750122
;8;-57.000000;200903.750122;514999.750122
;9;-57.000000;200904.250122;514999.750122
;10;-57.000000;200904.750122;514999.750122
```

I need it to look something like this:

```
1 -56.000000 200900.250122 514999.750122
2 -56.000000 200900.750122 514999.750122
```

Comment: Alice, please edit your question to show (1) the first few lines of your file (2) what those lines should look like after fixing. I'm fairly certain that we can help you, but we need to know exactly what you need to do. Also, Python 2.x or 3.X?

Comment: I need a python solution because doing it with the "find replace all" funcion in notepad causes my computer to compust!

Comment: John, i will edit it now.. it takes about 10 minutes to open the file though!!

Comment: Alice, (1) PLEASE answer: Python 2.X or 3.X? (2) Please start ANOTHER question with the file rename problem (and delete it from this question)

Comment: Alice, are you SURE that there are TWO logical records per line??? What is the significance of the leading `;`?? Are there in fact any line breaks at all???

Comment: Sorry, i changed it into code and now its more readable!

Comment: Alice, I am really dubious about that file structure. Please open up a Command Prompt Window (I'm presuming you are using Windows) and run this command ===>>> c:\wherever\python25 -c "print repr(open('your.file, 'rb').read(300))" <<<=== This will print an unambiguous representation of the first 300 bytes of your file, so we can see exactly what's in it. Please carefully copy/paste the text of the output (NOT a screenshot) into an edit of your question.

Comment: Alice, I've seen the "changed it into code" stuff and I'm still dubious. Please do the 300-byte dump as requested.

Comment: The file is exported from ArcMap - its an attribute table with columns! eumiro's answer solved my problem though! But should the file structure be something i should be worrying about?

Comment: It just looks crazy: TWO records on each line of what you showed, and each line after the first starts with a `;`. Have you tried importing your output file into the only-likes-space-or-tab program?

Comment: yeah it just cant read it and throw an error! I dont think there are 2 records on each line, each line signifies a point, which has a number, a Z value, a X and a Y value! Haha! I dont have much experience with ANY other types of file so i guess it looks normal to me!

Comment: also i think each line starts with a ; because it think there is a record infront of it which isnt there for some reason!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

How about this:

```
sed -i 's/;/ /g' yourBigFile.txt
```

This is not a Python solution. You have to start this in a shell. But if you use Notepad, I guess you are on Windows. So here a Python solution:

```
f1 = open('yourBigFile.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('yourBigFile.txt.tmp', 'w')
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line.replace(';', ' '))
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: just copy this straight into python? Do i have to write anything infront of it (sorry for my complete uselessness!)

Comment: @Alice, I have added a Python solution for you

Comment: I get the error: Message File Name Line Position 
Traceback    
    <module> C:\Documents and Settings\DuffA\Mijn documenten\Downloads\search_replace.py 6  
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: This is better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940101/removing-lines-from-a-csv-with-python-also-adds-an-extra-line?noredirect=1#comment40610727_25940101

Answer (score 21):

with Python, you can use [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html).

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.FileInput("file",inplace=1):
    line = line.replace(";"," ")
    print line,
```

this will replace all your ";" to spaces in place.

Comment: That adds an extra line break after every line for me in Windows.

Comment: @TheMouthofaCow - I've suggested an edit to fix that problem.

Comment: This solves the extra line problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940101/removing-lines-from-a-csv-with-python-also-adds-an-extra-line?noredirect=1#comment40610727_25940101

Answer (score 4):

Python 3.2 has added ability to use this as context manager, so that the files that fail during processing for some reason will always get closed:

```
import fileinput
def main():
    with fileinput.input(inplace=True) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.replace(";", " ")
            print(line, end='')
```

([inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4746474))

Use it by supplying it with the text file you want to process.

Comment: Tshepang What does this line do? print(line, end='')

Comment: "insert an empty string at the end of the line, instead of the usual `\n` character"