# How to remove specific columns of every nth line of csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I write result of sqlite 3 query to csv file like:

```
2221,5560081.75998,7487177.66,237.227573347,0.0,5.0,0.0
2069,5559223.00998,7486978.53,237.245992308,0.0,5.0,0.0
10001,5560080.63053,7487182.53076,237.227573347,0.0,5.0,0.0
1,50.1697105444,20.8112828879,214.965341376,5.0,-5.0,0.0
2,50.1697072935,20.8113209177,214.936598128,5.0,-5.0,0.0
10002,50.1697459029,20.8113995467,214.936598128,5.0,-5.0,0.0
1,50.1697105444,20.8112828879,214.965341376,-5.0,-5.0,0.0
2,50.1697072935,20.8113209177,214.936598128,-5.0,-5.0,0.0
10003,50.1697577958,20.8112608051,214.936598128,-5.0,-5.0,0.0
```

My first general question is how to pick every nth line of csv or txt file with python?

And my specific problem is how to remove last three columns of every two lines of csv file, leaving every third line with no changes?
The outpu would be like:

```
2221,5560081.75998,7487177.66,237.227573347
2069,5559223.00998,7486978.53,237.245992308
10001,5560080.63053,7487182.53076,237.227573347,0.0,5.0,0.0
1,50.1697105444,20.8112828879,214.965341376
2,50.1697072935,20.8113209177,214.936598128
10002,50.1697459029,20.8113995467,214.936598128,5.0,-5.0,0.0
1,50.1697105444,20.8112828879,214.965341376
2,50.1697072935,20.8113209177,214.936598128
10003,50.1697577958,20.8112608051,214.936598128,-5.0,-5.0,0.0
```

I've tried inter alia with:

```
fi = open('file.csv','r')
for i, row in enumerate(csv.reader(fi, delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True)):
    if i % 3 == 2:
        print row[0:]
    else:
        print row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]
```

Comment: Take a look at the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html), for quick ways to read / output csv data.

Comment: Since you're pulling the data from SQLite, does it not make more sense to grab the interesting data right there?

Comment: Good idea but I am not sqlite skilled enough:(

Comment: If you are hoping to **write** to the csv file (i.e. change it), you need to read and write, use `'r+'` rather than `'r'` (see [docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)) Alternatively, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4746215/1240268).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the nth line it's easiest to iterate through but you can use the [line cache module](http://docs.python.org/library/linecache.html) to grab it.

To answer the other part, assuming you want a new csv file with the desired qualities:

```
my_file = []
with open('file.csv','r') as fi:
    for i, row in enumerate(csv.reader(fi, delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True)):
         if i % 3 == 2:
             my_file.append(row)
         else:
             my_file.append(row[:-3])

#if you want to save a new csv file
with open('new_file.csv', 'wb') as new_fi:
    new_fi_writer = csv.writer(new_fi, delimiter=', ')
    for line in my_file:
        new_fi_writer.writerow(line)

#alternatively (if you just want to print the lines)
for line in my_file:
    print ' '.join(line)
```