# Removing lines from a csv with Python also adds an extra line

Tags: python, csv

This code, borrowed from another place on stackoverflow, removes all of the places that the csv has "None" written in it. However, it also adds an extra line to the csv. How can I change this code to remove that extra line? I think the problem is caused by `inplace`, but when I take `inplace` away the file is no longer altered by running the code.

```
def cleanOutputFile(filename):
    for line in fileinput.FileInput(filename,inplace=1):
        line = line.replace('None',"")
        print line
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would guess the extra line break simply comes from `print`?

Comment: I don't recommend modifying the file in place. Try and write to a new file.

Comment: This is strange, because I wouldn't expect the files to be changed at all by this code. `line = line.replace(...)` shouldn't actually modify the file, and of course neither does `print`. Are your "None"s really being removed?

Comment: They are being removed

Comment: @Kevin: `inplace=1` redirects standard output to the input file (which is something – to add to b10n's comment – I wouldn't recommend).

Comment: @b10n - help(fileinput) claims that the file is written to a backup file and then the existing file is rewritten.

Comment: okay, this is one crazy module. It is writing whatever goes to stdout to the file. I think I'd need a good stiff drink before I used it.

Comment: @balu was right, since fileinput is redirecting stdout, when you print the line, you get the original \n in the line plus the \n that print adds to it. It adds an extra line per csv line, not just 1 extra line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace all the `None's`:

```
with open(filename) as f:
     lines = f.read().replace("None","")
with open(filename,"w") as f1:
     f1.write(lines)
```

Using `rstrip` with `fileinput` should also work:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.FileInput(fileinput,inplace=1):
        print  line.replace('None',"").rstrip() # remove newline character to avoid adding extra lines in the output
```

Comment: This will just end up writing the last line to the file.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, how is that exactly?

Comment: Because everytime you open a file with `w`, it will be truncated.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, you should maybe try it out

Comment: This won't work on Windows, because opening `f1` will try to get exclusive access, which it can't get while `f` is open.

Comment: Also, reading the whole file into a giant string and then writing it back out may not be a great idea if the files are large.

Comment: @abarnert, it works for the OP and I have also added an answer as to how to use the OP's fileinput code using rstrip so it covers all eventualities.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: The fact that it works for the OP doesn't mean that it works on Windows unless you know the OP is on Windows. And it also doesn't mean it will work for other people who find the problem later, unless you know that none of them will be on Windows.

Comment: @abarnert so my fileinput answer won't work on windows? Also the last part of you answer recommends reading the whole file into memory but you have suggested in a comment here that it is not a good idea so which is it?

Comment: @abarnert - this worked on my windows machine but I think that it would generally be better if the first context is exited before the second one is opened. It would be a problem with large csvs, but a couple 100 meg would be fine.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I suggested it the lesser of two options in what is itself the least of five options, you just presented it as the right answer without even explaining that's what it's doing. Do you need see the difference? Also, why are you getting so defensive about comments? It's not like I'm personally attacking you and calling you an idiot, I'm just pointing out ways you could improve the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here has nothing to do with `fileinput`, or with the `replace`.

Lines read from a file always end in a newline.

`print` adds a newline, even if the thing you're printing already ends with a newline.

You can see this without even a file involved:

```
>>> a = 'abc'
>>> print a
abc
>>> a = 'abc\n'
>>> print a
abc

>>>
```

The solution is any of the following:

- `rstrip` the newlines off the input: `print line.rstrip('\n')` (or do the strip earlier in your processing)
- Use the "magic comma" to prevent `print` from adding the newline: `print line,`
- Use Python 3-style `print` with `from __future__ import print_function`, so you can use the more flexible keyword arguments: `print(line, end='')`
- Use `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print`.
- Completely reorganize your code so you're no longer writing to stdout at all, but instead writing directly to a temporary file, or reading the whole file into memory and then writing it back out, etc.