# Python: C engine does not support regex separators

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Attempting to upload a bunch of csv's to a database. The csvs are not necesarily always separated by a comma so I used a regular expression to ensure the correct delimiters are used. I then added the

```
error_bad_lines=False
```

in order to handle CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 127, saw 4
which resulted in me getting this error

```
ValueError: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators, but this causes 'error_bad_lines' to be ignored as it is not supported by the 'python' engine.
```

for the following code

Is there a workaround?

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa
csvList = []
tableList = []
filenames = find_csv_filenames(directory)
for name in filenames:  
    lhs, rhs = str(name).split(".", 1)
    print name
    dataRaw = pd.read_csv(name,sep=";|,",chunksize=5000000, error_bad_lines=False)
    for chunk in dataRaw:
        chunk.to_sql(name = str(lhs),if_exists='append',con=con)
```

Comment: What does your data look like?  If your fields aren't always separated by commas, it's not really CSV.  You may be able to hack something together, but if even using a regex separator doesn't allow you to consistently extract the fields, it sounds like you may be getting beyond what a CSV parser will handle.

Comment: the fields are separated by comma and semicolon as far as I know. I can manually go into each file and upload one at a time but then I have defeated the purpose of programming

Comment: Could you change these files? If yes you could preprocess your files and change `;` to `,` with python `re.sub` or linux `sed` for example.

Comment: I suppose I could do that some of the files have problems with loading into memory they have 30 columns 55 million rows kind of thing and it seems to blow up my 32GB of RAM pretty quick. ill look into re.sub

Comment: You could do it line by line and create another clean file (if you have enough storage to store it). Use answer for [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746190/find-and-replace-within-a-text-file) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could preprocess and change your file try to change `;` separator to `,` to make clean csv file. You could do it with [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) to change it inplace:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.FileInput('your_file', inplace=True):
    line = line.replace(';', ',')
    print(line, end='')
fileinput.close()
```

Then you could use `read_csv` with `c` engine and use parameter `error_bad_lines` or you could also preprocess them with that loop.

*Note: If you want to make backup of your file you could use `backup` parameter for `FileInput`*

Answer (score 9):

As per pandas parameter in this link  [Pandas-link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) 
if the separator is more than one character you need to add engine parameter as **'python'**.

try this,

```
dataRaw = pd.read_csv(name,sep=";|,",engine ='python',chunksize=5000000,
error_bad_lines=False)
```

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted. Good answer