# Python: How to delete line from text file

Tags: python

I am trying to delete one line of code from a text file and update it to a new value.

I have user inputted value in "line1" and "line2" and trying to update value of line1 to line2.
When I used below code,

```
f1=open("test.txt","a+")
f2=open("test.txt","a+")
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line.replace(line1,line2))
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

It doesn't replace the value of line1 to line2 but creates another line of line2.
So output in my text file is
value of line1
value of line2

How can I change this code to replace the value of line1 to line2 and delete the value of line1 from the text file?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. About your question, what do you have tried so far?

Comment: @Flux I tried this earlier, but instead of updating the user's information that I wanted to update, this code actually deleted information that should be updated. Thank you for the direction!

Comment: @felipsmartins I have tried different things. but I don't have a lot of knowledge of python, so this is very hard even though it might be very easy for some people. I've been stuck at this since yesterday.

Comment: See the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746190/find-and-replace-within-a-text-file-using-python

Comment: @Flux Thanks Flux! but this deleted everything in the file again.